# Running pip inside Docker container - won't install desired version of module

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am using the official `python:3.9-slim` Docker image and I am trying to install a specific version of a Python package using the following command inside my Dockerfile:

```
python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install --user --upgrade ansible-core~=2.11
```

Outside of a Docker container this will install `ansible-core` 2.11.6 at this moment in time - this is the correct version as it is the latest 2.11 release.

However, I can't get it to grab 2.11.x from inside my Docker container and it will only grab 2.12.0:

```
Collecting ansible-core~=2.11
  Downloading ansible-core-2.12.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
```

Is there something basic here that I am getting wrong?

Comment: Why can't you pin the dependency directly using `==` instead of `~=`?

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning your python version outside the container.

Comment: I don't want to be that specific and tie it to a specific minor patch version, but want to stick to a minor release. Outside the container has been tested against python3.6. The 2.11.x version doesn't have any restrictions which means it can't be installed under python3.9 - Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*

Comment: Does this help? 
`python3 -m pip --no-cache-dir install --user --upgrade "ansible-core>=2.11,<2.12"`

Comment: That works - Collecting ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11, Downloading ansible-core-2.11.6.tar.gz (7.0 MB), but why does that work and not ~=2.11?

Comment: I think you need the last segment of the version number:
`ansible-core~=2.11.0`
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release

Comment: ah ok.. so `==2.11.*` has the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why but if you add the last segment of the version number(2.11.0 instead of 2.11) to the command it will download the version you expected.